# How to carry sunglasses, so that I can easily put them on or off?

Tags: luggage

Has someone discovered a way to carry sunglasses, so that they can be put on or removed while riding?

I have tried two approaches, and both have drawbacks.

Carrying in a pouch, attached to the shoulder ring of the backpack results in scratched lens, because of the vibrations.

Carrying in the chest pocket of a jacket is possible only when it is sufficiently cold to wear a jacket.

My [backpack](http://www.tashev.bg/shop/product_info.php?language=en&idarticles=412) is large and with a lot of options for hanging equipment on it, so maybe some kind of attachable box or external pocket?

Comment: You could use glasses/goggles with transitions lenses, and always wear them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're riding in race kit, then you can use one of your jersey's rear pockets for this purpose. Putting the sunglasses away is really easy, but when getting them out again it can be a little fiddly to open the arms with one hand, the first few times you do it. You can even share the same pocket with something else, as long as it's not keys or a water bottle.

For race kit or light everyday clothes, you can hook one arm into the front of your T-shirt, shirt, jersey, jumper, etc. like a tourist does when walking around. You need to be confident of how stiff the arms are, but unless the sunglasses are wont to swing open on their own, it's perfectly safe. I wouldn't recommend trying it on a heavy jacket with a zip front or metal buttons, mind.

This is probably not a useful suggestion for you, but some rucksacks have chest straps to keep them stable on the move: it's usually possible to stick one arm of the glasses vertically through part of this assembly, such as the loop where the fastening is attached. If it's a snug fit, you can safely keep your glasses there even if the arm swings freely.

Answer (score 6):

If you are lucky/careful with your combination of sunglasses and helmet, you can store [them quite securely in helmet's vents](http://www.velominati.com/reverence/reverence-helmet-vents/#comment-5570), which makes it easy to put them on/off with a single hand:

[image: Sunglasses stored in helmet vents]

(quite hard to find a decent picture of this, screen-capture is from the Vuelta a España 2013, stage 14)

Comment: That's the [rules](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#39)!

Comment: `If they don’t fit, buy a new helmet.`

Answer (score 0):

Find a style of "Flip Up" sunglasses that appeals to you ( see link for examples ). Then you just put on the sunglasses at the beginning of the ride and you can flip them up or down as needed.

[http://www.amazon.com/Old-School-Steampunk-Circle-Glasses-Sunglasses/dp/B005P1KY8M/ref=sr_1_3?s=apparel&ie=UTF8&qid=1390267751&sr=1-3&keywords=retro+flip+up+sunglasses](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005P1KY8M)